# insert variable into db in c# code behind using sqldatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanted to insert a variable into a table in db using the `SqlDataSource`. Below is my code in aspx:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
       ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ACM_DBConnectionString %>" 
       DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [ContestRelation] WHERE [relationid] = @relationid" 
       InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [ContestRelation] ([contestid]) VALUES (@contestid)" 
       SelectCommand="SELECT [relationid], [contestid] FROM [ContestRelation]" 
       UpdateCommand="UPDATE [ContestRelation] SET [contestid] = @contestid WHERE [relationid] = @relationid">
   <DeleteParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="relationid" Type="Int32" />
   </DeleteParameters>
   <InsertParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="contestid" Type="Int32" />
   </InsertParameters>
   <UpdateParameters>
       <asp:Parameter Name="contestid" Type="Int32" />
       <asp:Parameter Name="relationid" Type="Int32" />
   </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and the code behind:

```
protected void ConfirmContest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            foreach (GridItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
            {
                GridDataItem dataitem = (GridDataItem)item;
                TableCell cell = dataitem["selectContest"];
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)cell.Controls[0];

                if (checkBox.Checked)
                {
                    string value = dataitem.GetDataKeyValue("contestid").ToString();
                    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("contestid", value);
                    SqlDataSource1.Insert();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('No data selected .');</script>");
        }
    }
```

The "value" variable is not inserted into the database table. Can anyone point me my mistakes? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved!

I actually cannot add an existing insert parameter, instead, I change to following code

```
string value = dataitem.GetDataKeyValue("contestid").ToString();
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("contestid", value);
SqlDataSource1.Insert();
```

to following code. And the problem is solved.

```
string value = dataitem.GetDataKeyValue("contestid").ToString();
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["contestid"].DefaultValue = value;
SqlDataSource1.Insert();
```